# alert messages on conditions using Json in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to show alert message in the view using json, it works fine when conditions are false or true,

but i need to show muliple alert messages when return Json(false);

**in action method:**

```
if (hispoint < totalpoint)
{
 // alert("you need more points") ;                  

return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);      
}

else if (data1 < 2 )
{
// alert("you need more than 2") ;

 return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

else if (data2 < 5 )
{
// alert("you need more than 5") ;

return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
 else
 {
 // redirect to another page
 return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

 }
```

**script in view:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.GetAll").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get($(this).attr("href"), function (isEligible) {
            if (isEligible) {

                window.location.href = "@Url.Action("GetGift")";
            }


            else {

                alertify.alert('Sorry !, try again');

              }


        })
    });
});
</script>
```

**my attempt:**

```
string message = "you need more than 2";      
return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

may i know how i can use else if in view and show alerts , i am newbie to json, any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is not the proper way to do, what you are trying to do.
but if it just for learning, you can change your code like this to solve.

In action :

```
string msg;
if (hispoint < totalpoint)
{
    msg = "you need more points";
}
else if (data1 < 2 )
{
    msg = "you need more than 2";
}
else if (data2 < 5 )
{
    msg = "you need more than 5";
}
return Json(msg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("a.GetAll").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.get($(this).attr("href"), function (msg) {
        if (msg) {
            alertify.alert(msg);
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = "@Url.Action("GetGift")";
          }
        })
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much Mukesh, this was exactly i was looking for, alert messages works fine, but i made some changes in script to make redirection work, some folk in stackoverflow has down voted for this simple question, no problem, but thank you to make me learn.

Comment: this is what i did in **script**: `$.get($(this).attr("href"), function (msg) {
                if (msg==true)
                {
                    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("GetGift")";

                }
                else
                {
                    if (msg)
                    {
                        alertify.alert(msg);
                    }
                }` and in **action method** : `string msg;
if (hispoint < totalpoint)
{
 msg = "you need more points";                                                        return Json(msg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}`

Comment: @stom, glad it helped you, but I could not understand the way you use 'msg' in conditions, with first condition you check bool value if (msg==true) and in second if(msg) which is null check. I suggest you just check for null, if msg is sent from controller means not null then show message and redirect otherwise.

Comment: thank you, to point out that, i will keep that tip for future use if needed